# Irreducible Polynomial of degree $~5~$ isomorphic to the direct Product of $S_3$

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, symmetric-groups

I'm tackling the following question:

Does there exist an irreducible polynomial $g(x) \in Q[x]$ of degree 5 with Galois group over Q isomorphic to $S_3×S_3$?

I think the answer is true. I figured out that $S_3×S_3$ is generated by the cycles
$(1,2,3) , (1,2), (4,5,6), (4,5)$ but I cant find a polynomial, whose Galois group contains them.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If $g$ is irreducible of degree $d$, then $d$ divides the order of the Galois group. So the answer is...

Answer (score 4):

Hint: We know that the size of the Galois group of a polynomial of degree $n$ divides $n!$.

Comment: $S3×S3$ has 36 elements. 36 does not divide $120 = 5!$ and thus there can't exist such a Galois group, right?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to infer that $S_3×S_3$ cannot be isomorphous to the Galois group of an irreducible quintic polynomial.

First as noted elsewhere the order of this group ($36$) does not divide the order of $S_5 (120)$.  We might also say that $S_3×S_3$ has two threefold symmetry elements independent of other symmetries whereas $S_5$ has only one, therefore by contradiction $S_3×S_3\not\in S_5$.  These two interpretations are of course r wr lated; the second threefold element of $S_3×S_3$ which $S_5$ doesn't have causes the invisibility requirement to fail.  If we had given up the second threefold element, specifying $S_3×Z_2$ instead of $S_3×S_3$, we would have met both the divisibility and containment requirements; $S_3×Z_2$ is a possible isomorphism for quintic polynomials.

Note that the last sentence does not contain the word "ireeducible".  In an irreducible polynomial of prime degree $p$, the Galois group must contain a $p$-fold symmetry element, and $S_3×S_3$ fails this requirement for $p=5$.  In fact even $S_3×Z_2$ fails also.  In the latter case, this does not stop $S_3×Z_2$ from being isomorphous to the Galois group of quintic polynomials, but it does mean that such quintic polynomials must be reducible.